# Is flying bad for your health?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, airport, cabin-pressure

I've always wondered if flying is bad for your health mainly because when you fly the air pressure changes a lot and i've always thought that, that can lead to negative side affects. So can someone please tell if there are any negatives to flying which may affect your health. And are there any reasons of why flying is good for your health??

Comment: The pressure change is only bad if you already have bad ears or respiratory system. The bigger issue is cosmic radiation causing cancer and disruption to your circadian rhythm from unsociable work patterns.

Comment: I find that it lowers my blood pressure quite a bit, so I fly as often as possible.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question - General Chuck Yeager who probably has tens of thousands of flight hours, just turned 94 years old. :-)

Comment: @RonBeyer Have you found a doctor yet who issues a prescription for this? Would you mind recommending?

Comment: @PerlDuck See any AME who is also a pilot.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was kidding—actually I was asking for a doctor who prescribes flights as a treatment against hypertension. And in a way my health insurance will accept without getting suspicious. :-) That'd be great. I'm just a pax, but I love flying.

Comment: I know, it was a light hearted reply... If you figure out that scam let me know, honestly my hourly aircraft rate is probably less than prescribed massages for people with bad backs...

Answer (score 2):

There has been some reports which have noted a higher than average incidence of certain cancers in aircrew. The reports are somewhat inconclusive

> Overall, the reports suggest that pilots are at increased risk of malignant melanoma, non-melanoma skin cancer, and possibly acute myeloid leukemia, and that cabin crew are at increased risk for breast cancer and malignant melanoma. However, the question remains as to whether the observed excesses are due to occupational exposures or non-occupational factors, such as reproductive history and lifestyle

<sub>Source: [British Medical Journal](http://oem.bmj.com/content/60/11/805.full)</sub>

Research is ongoing.

Comment: ....or days spent round the pool and at the beach on those long haul layovers ;)